# Double quotes with Sql Update

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, quotes, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to update a database with OleDb and .Net4.5.

My updates are working good , even if i use simple quote on a filed, but, when i input a double quote on a field, oledb raise an exception because of this double quote.

**Here is a an example of a request :**

```
string strRequest = "update " + strNomTable.Trim() + " set "
+ "evenotes = " + '"' + m_strNote.ToString().Trim() + '"' 
+ " where eveNum = " + '"' + strEvtNumeroString.Trim() + '"';
```

Have you an idea how i could avoid simple and double quotes ?
Note : I tried to use SQL Parametrized updates, bu my DataBase don't appear to support this.

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: A Visual Fox Pro Database ( DBF File) with VFP OleDb.

Comment: Just a tip, String.Format() can help make query strings more readable.

Comment: strRequest also seems to evaluate to an invalid syntax. there is a comma before the where

Comment: Yes it's a copy in my copy/paste on the website. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A few options come to mind. Since I do not know what kind of database you are using, I am just guessing:

1. Use parameters. I know you have tried it, but I would suggest to try again. If it failes, try the following:
2. Remove the comma for the "where" (one line up!).
3. Change all your double quotes inside your SQL-statement into single quotes. Literal text should be quotes like `"'" + m_strNote.ToString().Trim() + "'"` and not `'"' + m_strNote.ToString().Trim() + '"'`
4. Replace all single single quotes (') in your values with double single quotes (''): `"'" + m_strNote.ToString().Trim().Replace("'", "''")  + "'"`

If you combine option 2 till 4 you will get this:

```
string strRequest = "update " + strNomTable.Trim() + " set "
+ "evenotes = '" + m_strNote.ToString().Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "' "
+ "where eveNum = '" + strEvtNumeroString.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "'";
```

**Visual Fox Pro Database and OleDbParameters**

You can use OleDbParameters. Start the name with an `@`. So:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(
    "update " + strNomTable.Trim() + " set "
    + "evenotes = @evenotes "
    + "where eveNum = @eveNum");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@evenotes", m_strNote.ToString().Trim());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eveNum", strEvtNumeroString.Trim());
```

Comment: I tried to use Parametrized but i have a bad "syntax error" exception :\

Comment: That is why I offered you two other options. But perhapse you could create another question, post your code with parameters and ask if somebody sees the error. A lot of people abondon the correct way to easy and stray from the right path.

Comment: I already ask for the parametrized whitout succes ! In addition, i tried your second solution ( the .replace()) with an sql Error too :(

Comment: 1) Where did you ask the question (link?) and 2) what is the error?

Comment: The link is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384635/syntax-error-on-a-sql-parametrized-update-command-c-sharp

Comment: And for the error message : " Command contains unreconized phrase/keywords"

Comment: I modified my answer. I think you should use single quotes to mark your literals.

Comment: To mark my litteral ? Directly on my SQL command ? eg : string strRequest = 'update ' + strNomTable.Trim() + ' set '
+ 'evenotes = ' + '"' + m_strNote.ToString().Trim() + '"' + ' , '
+ ' where eveNum = ' + '"' + strEvtNumeroString.Trim() + '"';

Comment: `Literals` are the values you use inside your state. So the result of `strNomTable.Trim()` which you put in your SQL-string is a literal. If modified line 2 with a beter example.

Comment: I noticed a great bug in your statement: Remove the comma before the "where" (one line up).

Comment: With simple quote, i have a "Syntax Error." Message. I would like to use SQL Parametrized, but i have worked all day long in order to correct this but i didn't found the right solution.

Comment: For a Comma, it's a typo when i paste the code on the website.

Comment: Well... in that case, remove it from your question :)

Comment: I'd suggest you: 1) follow up the answers of your prev. question and this question (so single quotes, etc.) then 2) make an exact copy of your code which contain the error WIHTOUT typo's. If you do not you will repeatingly get the same answes from different people (about the comma, about double quotes, etc.) which do not help you. In short: give us a good starting point.